# Does using multiple context.drawImage() still lead to one draw call on GPU or does canvas have to refresh each time

Tags: javascript, canvas, optimization, gpu

If I run the following code:

```
// ...
for (var index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
    var image = images[index];
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
// ...
```

Does the GPU still use only one draw call for this or would one have to come up with a solution using `getImageData` and `putImageData`?

Comment: How would they do it in a single draw call? And where would you take the pixel values to set in putImageData? What is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: @Kaiido I'm so sorry for the late reply, but to do one draw you could use webgl, or you could create your own scripts for updating the `imageData` of the canvas.

Comment: But you need to do composition, be it the simple multiplication of *source-over*. Then you need to draw each image one after the other don't you? Also, if you want to go the putImageData way, you'd need to have the original image's ImageData to take the values and do the composition yourself on the ImageData to be put. So you'd have to at least draw it once before anyway. Can you recentrate your question on your practical issue? I feel we could find help for you, but I'm not sure you're asking the correct question here.

Comment: @Kaiido OK, I think I need to put you in context. This question was in relation to creating html5 games. In this case, you would have an array of sprites and each iteration, you run the sprite's `.draw()` function. I was just wondering if the browser would be able to figure this and batch all the `drawImage` calls before it renders onto the screen.

Comment: Now, to respond to what you said, yes it would be simple source-over composition since this is the default anyways (and also since games rarely need anything more complex). If we went the ImageData route, we wouldn't be drawing each image but manipulating the pixel raw data and then replacing the main _display_ ImageData with the new modified version. This means we actually draw once. I wanted to try this out, but didn't want to waste time if the browser already does this. Hence the question.

Comment: So to recap, the question I have is whether the browser batches `drawImage` calls and if not what good options (apart from webgl) are there to achieve batched draw calls on a 2D canvas context.